# iOS build setup fails on Azure with file exists error

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am running Azure build pipeline for iOS with Xcode 9 version. I have cocoapods step which does pod install. Then in the build step, I am getting the below error. I have clean build option enabled. Also I tried running a bash script with `rm -rf Pods` before running cocoapods step, but I still get the same file exits error, but sometimes, with different file. Any idea how to fix this?

```
...
▸ Linking GoogleToolboxForMac
▸ Generating 'GoogleToolboxForMac.framework.dSYM'
▸ Building Pods/GrowingTextView [Release]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Processing GrowingTextView-Info.plist
▸ Copying GrowingTextView-umbrella.h
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `mkdir': File exists @ dir_s_mkdir - build (Errno::EEXIST)
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:239:in `fu_mkdir'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `reverse_each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:215:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:200:in `mkdir_p'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/reporters/reporter.rb:29:in `finish'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/reporters/junit.rb:65:in `finish'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:89:in `each'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:89:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/xcpretty:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/xcpretty:23:in `<main>'
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, on Azure Pipelines, error 65 with cocoapods is related to Signing and Certificates while XCode tries to sign the Pod projects which do not support signing.

Have you enabled or disabled the `useXcpretty: 'false'`? I would recommend disabling it as it potentially hides the real XCode error in the Pipeline's logs.

I had to add the following at the end of my `Podfile` to force disabling signing in the pods:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'] = ''
    config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
    config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = 'NO'
  end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER'] = ''
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = 'NO'
        config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. I had also updated all my pods to latest.